# SC failure command with wildcard

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a `batch` script to configure the recovery options (First failure, second failure, subsequent failure)  i.e. `SC failure` for a custom server installed as a Windows service.

The problem is the Service Name of the Windows service will be different for each installation. The Service Name will be in format **ProductName_ServerName_Version** where the **ProductName** and **Version** will keep changing and **ServerName** will be constant. So I wanted to find the installed Windows Service and configure the Recovery options via a batch file which I can use for all installations since the **ServerName** part is constant and I want to lookup using that. I use the below script.

```
@echo off
set "service=TestSrv"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%# in ('sc query type^= service^|find /i "SERVICE_NAME:"^|findstr /i /b /c:"SERVICE_NAME: %service%"') do (
    set "nservice=%%#"
)
echo %nservice%
sc failure "%nservice%" reset= 60000 actions= restart/60000/restart/60000/restart/60000
```

Here TestSrv is the **ServerName** and the above script only returns the Service Name correctly if it is starting with TestSrv. I want a %ServerName% lookup and how to achieve that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to accept that you will not have any other services within the system which have a name containing `_TestSrv_` then you could use WMI to retrieve the service name.

For example, *(please change `TestSrv` on line `1` and complete the last line as necessary)*:

```bat
@Set "ServerName=TestSrv"&Set "nservice="
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe /R %__AppDir__% mof.xsl 2^>NUL'
)Do @For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%H In ('%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Service^
 Where "Name Like '%%[_]%ServerName%[_]%%'" Get Name /Format:"%%G" 2^>NUL'
)Do @Set "nservice=%%H"
@If Not Defined nservice Exit /B 1
@Echo %nservice%
@%__APPDIR__%sc.exe failure "%nservice%" etc…
```

Comment: Thank you so much Compo. The script is running perfectly.